# Fatal error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::nonce_field()

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am getting an error on the cart page "**Call to undefined method WooCommerce::nonce_field()**".

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::nonce_field() in C:\xampp\htdocs\stemorg\wp-content\themes\breeze-child\woocommerce\cart\cart.php on line 120**

cart.php on line 120 here is the code:
**$woocommerce->nonce_field('cart');**

I am very tired of this error. 
Please, anyone, help me how to fix this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: change ” $woocommerce->nonce_field ” to “wp_nonce_field”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Products section in wp-admin panel doesn’t depend on the theme. If you select default WordPress theme you’ll see the same issue. This is WordPress configuration.
To fix the errors you need edit files via FTP, open the file wp-content/themes/your_theme/woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php on line 67 and replace

```
$woocommerce->nonce_field

     with

  wp_nonce_field
```

and the file wp-content/themes/your_theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php on line 3 and replace

```
 $woocommerce->show_messages();

      with

  wc_print_notices();
```